# database: Add value to existing row

Tags: database, numbers, row, addition

Hi I am pretty new to coding and such. I got a database with one row and one value of 40. I also got a php that when i enter a number it will be added to the database as a new row. Is there any way to add this number to the existing number 40? example: if i add 60 the new value will be 100. Is there any code in php that tells the database to add to an existing row? right now i got this code in php `$sql = "insert into $DB_Table (score) values('$scoretext');";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the way you could do this is by updating the existing row.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

Hope that helps..

**EDIT**

```
$sql = "UPDATE score SET columname= ('$scoretext') WHERE id/columname = '$id' or xyz";
```

my syntax is not 100% correct but you should get the idea. you should store this in the existing query. do you have id column in the row so you know which row it is.

Comment: I want this to happen automatically each time someone enters a number without me having to do anything. Is it possible that this updating code is activated automatically when a user insert a row?

Comment: yes basically you change the sql statement to update the value of the column. Please view my edit